# jQuery- executing events in order, one after the other

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a piece of code which is designed to:
On('click')

1. fade Out element 1
2. fade In element 2

it looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #element1 {width:200px; height:200px; background-color:red; }
        #element2 {width:200px; height:200px; background-color:green; display:none; }
        </style>

        <script language="JavaScript" src="jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('body').on('click','#element1',function()
                {
                    $('#element1').fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#element2').fadeIn('slow');  
                });

                $('body').on('click','#element2',function()
                {
                    $('#element2').fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#element1').fadeIn('slow');  
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="element1">element1</div>
        <div id="element2">element2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when clicking it is fading them both simultaneously. Is there a way to make it so that it executes the fadeOut first, and only once that is complete, then the fadeIn?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `callback` like this:

```
$('#element1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#element2').fadeIn('slow'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a function that fires once the fadeOut has finished, like so:

```
$('#element1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#element2').fadeIn('slow'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you need to use your other selector to fadeout in callback function of the fadeIn method. Yet you can do something to do it in a single selector the way below.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','[id^="element"]',function(){
         if(this.id === "element1"){
            $('#element1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('#element2').fadeIn('slow');
            });
         }else{
            $('#element2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('#element1').fadeIn('slow');
            });
         }
    });
});
```

[Try the demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d88ZQ/)